# outputting a record highlighted in django change admin page

Tags: python, django

I need to print a highlighted record from within djangos' admin page that the user selects.
I have added the action to print a selected record but cannot seem to get any further.

I have tested reportlab creating a 'hello world' pdf from within my 'print_member' action within admin.py & that runs ok.

My question is how do I grab that 'just-highlighted-record-selected-for-printing' and feed that queryset data to the reportlab canvas call.

I cannot find anywhere in the django docs just how to go from selecting a record in the admin page to actually returning that record in the response part of the `HttpResponse` call.

My current code is:

```
  def print_member( self, request, queryset ):
       rows_updated = queryset.update( status = 'p' )
       if rows_updated == 1:
           message_bit = "member detail was collected successfully !!"
       self.message_user( request, "%s   detailed ready for printing!!" % message_bit )
       response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'application/pdf' )
       response[ 'Content-Disposition' ] = 'attachment; filename="member_label.pdf"'
       p = canvas.Canvas( response )
       details = list( request )
       p.drawString( 100,100,detail_string )
       p.showPage()
       p.save()
       return response
```

---

my test code admin.py is as follows :-
  def print_member( self, request, queryset ):
       rows_updated = queryset.update( status = 'p' )
       if rows_updated == 1:
           message_bit = "member detail was collected successfully !!"
       self.message_user( request, "%s   detailed ready for printing!!" % message_bit )
       response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'application/pdf' )
       response[ 'Content-Disposition' ] = 'attachment; filename="member_label.pdf"'
       p = canvas.Canvas( response )
       details = list( request )
       p.drawString( 100,100,detail_string )
       p.showPage()
       p.save()
       return response

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are already using admin actions? If so, could you show the code you are now using? Else, first see Saul's answer.

Comment: So what I am asking is how I go from the queryset.update ( if that is correct because I do not update the model with the actual status = 'p' ) to filling in the 'details' for the reportlab canvas call. If this is not the accepted way of printing out a record selected in the django admin page then how would you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

my advise is to use admin actions.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

there you'll get queryset. then just iterate though this queryset and do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi Saul, thx but as a newbie to the inner workings of django I don't see how to get the selected record available to me from the admin page. ie: I need to see how I get the queryset data into the 'canvas' call.

Comment: finally got it with the iteration since queryset holds the member surname and I only have to do some sql to grab the record with that surname , so thx for the tips.